# How to capture what application is set to start on given shortcut on Windows?

Tags: windows, lenovo-laptop, procmon

I've got Lenovo laptop which has a **Fullscreen Magnifier** function (zooms the screen). It's activated by pressing **Fn + Space shortcut**. Because I use the notebook on external display where I don't have a keyboard with Fn key, I would like to be able to start the application also by clicking on some desktop shortcut.

With SysInternals Procmon I've found an application which is run after pressing Fn+Space. The application is located at:

```
C:\Program Files\Lenovo\ZOOM\TpScrex.exe
```

But when I try to run it manually, it won't start (won't zoom the screen as by pressing the shortcut). Is there any way how to determine what is exactly launched (including switches) after pressing Fn+Space?

I've also tried to running:

```
C:\Program Files\Lenovo\ZOOM\TpScrex.exe /?
C:\Program Files\Lenovo\ZOOM\TpScrex.exe /help
```

But it seems there is no help attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional command line arguments may be required. Check if there are any. You can do that even with the built-in Task Manager by enabling the *Command line* column.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use AutoHotKey for this and simulate the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key which may work for you.

It may not be easy to map the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, but [this post may help](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/282-fn-key-on-a-notebook/)